# Inserting date range arrays daterange[]

Tags: postgresql, syntax, range-types

I'm trying to insert the value of an attribute of a tuple, which would be an array of date ranges, i.e. a `daterange[]`, in a previous tuple accepted the value:

```
{"[2013-05-08,2018-03-22)"}
```

But now I would like to insert this array, with more than one range:

```
{"[19-03-2018,29-12-2020)","[21-06-2018,29-12-2020)", "[17-07-2018,29-12-2020)", 
        "[18-04-2018,30-07-2018]", "[01-08-2019,19-11-2019]"}
```

I have tried all possible solutions,putting the outer quotes

```
 '{"[19-03-2018,29-12-2020)","[21-06-2018,29-12-2020)", "[17-07-2018,29-12-2020)", 
        "[18-04-2018,30-07-2018]", "[01-08-2019,19-11-2019]"}'
```

Putting the internal single quotes instead of the double ones, but nothing works.

Gives me the error:

> ```
> argument formats can't be mixed
> ```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using [ and )? Create a db<>fiddle that demonstrates your scenario

Comment: Hmm, the double quotes do work for me (though the date format has to be changed): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c84490e4b30744379c773c734c9e6702

Comment: Your Postgres version and the client and version in use would be essential to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This would be legal syntax - using ISO format for dates (*YYYY-MM-DD*), which is *always* a good idea as it does not depend on the current setting of [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE). Your example only works with `datestyle = 'DMY'`.

```
 '{"[2018-03-19,2020-12-29)","[2018-06-21,2020-12-29)"}'
```

You can always ask Postgres to show you:

```
test=# SELECT ARRAY ['[2018-03-19,2020-12-29)'::daterange ,'[2018-06-21,2020-12-29)'];
                         array                         
-------------------------------------------------------
 {"[2018-03-19,2020-12-29)","[2018-06-21,2020-12-29)"}
(1 row)
```

The error msg you report does not seem to be generated by Postgres.

> ```
> argument formats can't be mixed
> ```

Are you, by any chance, using an outdated version of pgAdmin III? See:

- [pgAdmin argument formats can't be mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59842660/939860)